# Creating multiple users for postgis db created with qgiscloud plugin?

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-plugins, database

I have created a PostGIS database using **qgiscloud plugin**.

I would like to give access to 3 more users (usernames and associated passwords) in order for them to update 3 specific layers only, without having privileges to edit other layers.

Is it possible and how?